# Vue disabled button trigger event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

Hey I am really new to Vue and for this project I want to trigger event on disabled button. Is there a way to trigger event on disabled button?

**JsFillde Code Link** = https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/Lg4vcj97/6/

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <b-button @click="disabledButton" disabled >Disabled</b-button>
  <b-button @click="enabledButton" >Enabled</b-button>
</div>
```

**Method**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {

  },
  methods: {
    disabledButton(){
        console.log('clicked disabled');
    },
    enabledButton(){
        console.log('clicked enabled');
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the button truly need to be disabled or can you simulate a disabled state?

I added bootstrap css for the 'disabled' class here, but it's not necessary.

```
// template
<b-button  @click="disabledButton"  class="disabled-btn disabled" >Disabled</b-button>
  

// css
.disabled-btn{
    cursor: default !important;
    pointer-events: unset !important;
    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qjacr38y/23/